# Resolution graph of higher dimensional ADE singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, singularity-theory, resolution-of-singularities

I am looking for different configurations of the exceptional divisors arising from blowing up a higher dimensional ADE singularity (see p. 240 of [this](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01350716.pdf) article of Bruns for a description of such singularities). In particular, is there a higher dimensional analogue of the Dynkin diagram (in the surface case)? Any reference that studies such questions will be most welcome.